# Taking 3 inputs in the same line in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to take 3 integer inputs on the same line using split, but it throws an error

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'list'

Here is my code

```
  n,a,k = int(input().split())
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
n,a,k = map(int, input().split())
```

`int` can receive one string only.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `map` like so :

```
n,a,k = map(int, input().split())
```

as the `split` function returns a `list` and not a `str`.
`map` applies the `int` function to every element (`str`) of the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Since others have given a `map` solution, here is one using a simple list comprehension:

```
n,a,k = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Does it have an advantage over `map()`?  Not really, but some prefer this approach.

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
import ast
n,a,k = ast.literal_eval(','.join(input().split()))
print(n,a,k,sep='\n')
```

Example Output:

```
1 2 3
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish the same using the below procedural approach even if your input contains alphabets with at least 3 numbers or more.

> If you will enter a string with less than 3 numbers also, function wil take care of it and return 0 for the corresponding variables. Examples are included at very bottom. Please have a look.

```
import re

def get_inputs(n=3):
    inp = input('Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: ').strip()
    arr =  re.sub(r'[^0-9]+', ' ', inp).strip().split()

    if len(arr) < n:
        for i in range(n):
            try:
                arr[i]
            except IndexError as e:
                arr.append(0)

    n, a, k, *rest = list(map(int, arr))

    return (n, a, k, rest)

# Start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get 3 numbers
    out1 = get_inputs() 
    n, a, k, rest = out1

    print('n =', n)
    print('a =', a)
    print('k =', k)
    print('rest = ', rest)
```

## Output

```
rishi@Rishidev MINGW64 /c/Rishikesh67/Projects/Working/hygull.github.io/codes/python3.6 (master)
$ python get_numbers.py
Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: Hello, I like 65, 45 and 90 ok.
n = 65
a = 45
k = 90
rest =  []


rishi@Rishidev MINGW64 /c/Rishikesh67/Projects/Working/hygull.github.io/codes/python3.6 (master)
$ python get_numbers.py
Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: 12, 23 and 67 are nice but 34 and 23 also.
n = 12
a = 23
k = 67
rest =  [34, 23]


rishi@Rishidev MINGW64 /c/Rishikesh67/Projects/Working/hygull.github.io/codes/python3.6 (master)
$ python get_numbers.py
Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: 12 34 56
n = 12
a = 34
k = 56
rest =  []


rishi@Rishidev MINGW64 /c/Rishikesh67/Projects/Working/hygull.github.io/codes/python3.6 (master)
$ python get_numbers.py
Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: 45 12    34   21 12 hello 99
n = 45
a = 12
k = 34
rest =  [21, 12, 99]


rishi@Rishidev MINGW64 /c/Rishikesh67/Projects/Working/hygull.github.io/codes/python3.6 (master)
$ python 1.py
Enter a sentence with at least 3 numbers included: Now 67 is best for me.
n = 67
a = 0
k = 0
rest =  []
```